# python accessing unequal row and column

Tags: python

I have two tex files which contain unequal number of rows and columns. Now I want to compare list of one tex file with other file, and if it is match, then print corresponding number. For e.g. my two files look like

```
test1.txt       test2.txt

XCJ2200,       XCJ1945,A,0.1
XCJ2345,E      XCJ2200,B,0.2
XCJ2568,F      XCJ2450,C,0.3
....           XCJ2590,D,0.4
               XCJ3000,E,0.5
               ....
```

I want to match column 1 and 2 of test1.txt with column 1 and 2 of test2.txt and want following final output

```
XCJ2200 0.2
XCJ2345 0.5
XCJ2568
```

So far I have written following code but it is not giving answer as I want:

```
reader1=csv.reader(open('test1.txt','rb'))
reader2=csv.reader(open('test2.txt','rb'))
col1=[];col2=[];Col1=[];Col2=[];Col3=[]
for row in reader1:
  col1.append((row[0]))
  col2.append((row[1]))
for row in reader2:
  Col1.append((row[0]))
  Col2.append((row[1]))
  Col3.append((row[2]))
for i in range(len(col1)):
 for j in range(len(Col1)):
  if Col1[j]==col1[i] or Col2[j]==col2[i]:
     print col1[i],Col3[j]
  else:
    print col1[i]
```

This code give me the following output

```
  XCJ2200
  XCJ2200 0.2
  XCJ2200
  XCJ2200
  XCJ2200
  XCJ2345
  XCJ2345
  XCJ2345
  XCJ2345
  XCJ2345 0.5
  XCJ2568
  XCJ2568
  XCJ2568
  XCJ2568
  XCJ2568
```

This code is printing col 1 of test1.txt in multiple times of length of col 1 of test2.txt. I know that there is something wrong in last loop condition. Please let me know possible solution for this problem.

Comment: Don't use the else statement to print the column you don't want?

Comment: Then it will just print  XCJ2200 0.2   XCJ2345 0.5

Comment: @viralparekh Is `"XCJ2200"` etc. always unique in either csv1 or csv2 ?

Comment: Yes each XCJ**** is unique in both files.

Comment: @viralparekh Your code compares every column against every other column. Do you really want to do that? Or do you want to compare (1st column vs 1st column) and (2nd column vs 2nd column). Do you have more than 2 columns to test actually? Do you want to output a row when any of the test conditions pass or when all the test conditions pass?

Comment: @viralparekh More questions. Are the letters (e.g. "A", "B", "C") unique in each file? If the letters match instead of the ID (e.g. "XCJ2568") do you want to print the letters or the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test1.txt

```
XCJ2200,
XCJ2345,E
XCJ2568,F
```

test2.txt

```
XCJ1945,A,0.1
XCJ2200,B,0.2
XCJ2450,C,0.3
XCJ2590,D,0.4
XCJ3000,E,0.5
```

code

```
import csv

data1 = list(csv.reader(open('test1.txt','rb')))
data2 = list(csv.reader(open('test2.txt','rb')))

for d in data1:
    lookup = [x for x in data2 if any(z in x for z in d)]
    print '{0} {1}'.format(d[0], lookup[0][2] if lookup else '')
```

Comment: your code is not checking the second condition i.e. col2(test1.txt)==Col2(test1.txt).

Comment: @viralparekh You need to provide a more detailed data input and output example. We are having to guess your specifications. For example you could post sample data files and the exact output you expect from them.

Comment: You should try to identify what the OP did wrong in his original code, and explain the code and concepts you used to solve the problem. Just giving the answer in code doesn't help the asker to learn, and it has no value to any visitors searching for similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your specification needs some clarifications but this might do what you are looking for. Please try it. I hope the code might give you some ideas about easier ways to write code as well.

```
import csv


with open('test1.txt') as f:  # this avoids the trouble of remembering to close files
    data1_ids, data1_letters = zip(*csv.reader(f))
with open('test2.txt') as f:
    data2_ids, data2_letters, data2_numbers = zip(*csv.reader(f))


for i, (data1_id, data1_letter) in enumerate(zip(data1_ids, data1_letters)):
    if (data1_id in data2_ids) or (data1_letter in data2_letters):
        print('{} {}'.format(data1_id, data2_numbers[i]))
    else:
        print(data1_id)
```

Comment: This code is also not satisfying the second condition. I kindly request you to see what output I want in my question. Thanks.

Comment: @viralparekh I have updated the answer but please follow up on updating your question.